# mobilefirst / worklight - hybrid application background color

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-runtime

During startup sequence there is a split second where the skinLoader is active loading the index.html. During this time the background color is white. Is there a way of permanently setting the background color of the application so that it matches the background color of your splash/index page?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting Worklight 6.2, you can fully customize the splash screen of your application. This can be from extending the duration the splash image is displayed to creating a completely different user experience.

You can read about this [in the Common UI tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#splashscreen).

Options you can try:

1. Alter the white background color in skinLoader.js; this file can be found in the environment's native folder (iphone\native\www\default\ and similarly for other environments)
2. Extend the splash image duration as demonstrated in the tutorial
3. Follow the instructions in the Knowledge Center (also linked to from the tutorial) to create something else altogether.